# Foundation Grid System on Tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a table like:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to use the [grid system of foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) on my tables. For Example I want to specify that my columns are of size 2, 4, 6 which gives the 12 columns of the foundation grid system.

I tried this SCSS:

```
.trow {
  @include grid-row();
}

.tsize-2 {
  @include grid-column(2);
}

.tsize-4 {
  @include grid-column(4);
}

.tsize-6 {
  @include grid-column(6);
}
```

Applied in my HTML like this:

```
                 <thead>
                    <tr class="trow">
                        <td class="tsize-4">Title</td>
                        <td class="tsize-6">Description</td>
                        <td class="tsize-2">Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

It still did not display the columns in the correct size.

**How do I use the Foundation Grid System on Tables?**

Answer (score 0):

The Foundation grid system, like most grid systems float all columns in a row (which is subsequently clear fixed).  Applying floats to table td's is going to produce some weird outcomes.

If you want to make your tables responsive search for "responsive table" solutions, like this one:

http://foundation.zurb.com/responsive-tables.html

Alternatively, you can use a div structure to emulate tables thus allowing you so use the grid system.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t4vj72d6/2/

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
   width: 75%
}

<tr class="row">
    <td class="small-2 columns">Title</td>
    <td class="small-4 columns">Description</td>
    <td class="small-6 columns">Price</td>
</tr>
```

I tried it out in this fiddle and it works fine as long as you set the width of your table.  I know it's not sass, but I don't see why it would be any different.